# show html code inside box like yahoo html messages

Tags: html

I want view user html code inside box like Gmail,Yahoo html messages.

I will use code in something like mail my old code and I think I am so stupid!

```
<div class="mydiv" style="border:1px #000 solid">
THE USER CODE
</div>
```

The problem here is if user html code is starts with `</div>` my own div will be closed and rest code will show outside my div!

So, how i can done this job professionally? I tried searching!

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="mydiv" style="border:1px #000 solid">
<textarea style="width:100%;height:120px;border:2px solid black;padding:4px;">
THE USER CODE
</textarea>
</div>
```