# protect my html div

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [show html code inside box like yahoo html messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409240/show-html-code-inside-box-like-yahoo-html-messages)

first, i am sorry for moderators .. i have made this question yeasterday and got no answers!

i have html form

allow users to post them html code and then i show it by my php

here is my php code

```
<?php

 $html = '<div id="my_box" style="border:1px #000 solid">'; //my own div!
 $_POST['user_html'] = '</div><p>Any thing</p>'; //html code of visitor! , i want display it inside my own div above
 $html .= $_POST['user_html'];
 $html .= '</div>'; //close my own div!
 echo $html;

?>
```

if you tried this code you will find the user html code displaying outside my own div box

because his code is start with `</div>` <-- he closed my div!

So , how i can fix it and display his code without affect my own div ?

i need something like iframe!

--NOTE 1

the story above is just to make you understand .. i am not crazy to make project do this stupid job!

--NOTE 2

the php codes is just for example to make you understand .. my project is based html i want fix it by java or html .. not php

---

Another example

Yahoo , Gmail html messages

they display the html messages inside them html box

i have tired searching ,,,

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Edit your other question to make it clearer. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the content put in by the user. Thus it gets displayed as `</div><p>Any thing</p>` and isn't interpreted.

Comment: i want it interpreted! .. but without affect my div! please see my last note about Google,Ymail html messages .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function:

```
$html = '<div id="my_box" style="border:1px #000 solid">'; //my own div!
$_POST['user_html'] = '</div><p>Any thing</p>'; //html code of visitor! , i want display it inside my own div above
$html .= htmlentities($_POST['user_html']);
$html .= '</div>'; //close my own div!
echo $html;
```

**Edit:** Actually, that'll only work if you want to display the raw HTML. If you want it to be rendered as HTML, then you'll have to use an iframe somehow. Sorry, I don't know how you'd do this (well, I do, but it's long and convoluted and someone else can probably help better).

Comment: yes i want show the user html affects but without affect my div .. like iframe .. i hope someone else help me .. thank you CanSpice